# IIS Windows Authentication Breaks .NET Core Memory Cache

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, caching, memory

The security for my .NET Core (2.1) application utilizes memory caching (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory) to store individual user access in memory (15 minute expiration) to cut back on calls to the database.

This worked perfectly running locally and deployed to our development environment.  However, I just deployed the application to our sandbox environment, and the caching isn't working at all (in the sandbox environment).

After poking around in IIS, I found that the server-level Windows Authnetication setting is set to disabled in the development environment, but enabled in the sandbox environment.  I disabled this setting in sandbox, and it fixed the issue.  While it's great to have the issue narrowed down, I would like to avoid disabling this setting as there are about a dozen other apps running on these servers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That may be a red herring. Does your application use Windows Auth too? If so I'd suspect this one is preferred over your Individual Accounts and your Windows Authentication is used as default scheme, where your others isn't so when obtaining the id or identity you will get the wrong principal user. If so, try changing default auth scheme ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes))

Comment: You can set default scheme to ASP.NET Core Identity via `.AddAuthorization(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)` (which is basically `CookiePrefix + ".Application"` ([see source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/IdentityConstants.cs#L15))

Comment: That's the weird part, Windows Auth is enabled at the app level - which is fine.  However, enabling Windows Auth at the server level breaks it.  I will take a look at the documentation.  Thank you!